# Driving ULN2064 with 74HC595 for 12V motor loads

Tags: h-bridge, 74hc595, uln2803

I've made a circuit with ( Arduino + 74HC595 + ULN2803 ) to drive 20 hobby motors using 12V 10A Supply.

Initially It Looks Good, But when i started running one motor,

- Motor running too slowly and sometime not running
- Voltage getting down to 1.2 V from 12 V
- ULN2803 Heating Up
- Even few channels damaged

I found that motor drawing more current, then i stacked TWO ULN2803s with NO use.

After some search i found ULN2064B comes with 1.5 A Per channel output.

Question : How can i drive ULN2064B with 74HC595 or similar ???

Expecting circuits, explanations As i'm not proficient in electronics.

Comment: A circuit diagram plus a photo of your apparatus would go a long way to help us understand your situation, and be in a position to offer meaningful assistance to you.

Comment: Which variant of the ULN2803 are you using - there are several types.
What type of DC "hobby motor" are you using?  
What power supply are you using?

You need to provide more detail, else we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

> Question : How can i drive ULN2064B with 74HC595 as "H BRIDGE" ???

You can't, neither with ULN2803. This driver is not a H-bridge driver.
The stepper motor would require a chopper (current limiting) and not a simple buffer. For simple applications you may use ULNs to drive unipolar stepper motor, but with low voltage and low speeds. \$V=I_{rated}\cdot R_{coil}\$.

Comment: NOT stepper motors, Just DC Hobby Motors, Precisely 130 size dc motor

Comment: H Bridge with multiple ULN2064s , As I need to drive 20+ motors

Comment: @sur Same rules apply and no H-bridge possible. 130 dc size motor doesn't mean anything, rated current, rated voltage, rated speed, power/torque characteristics,...

Comment: Thanks Marko Bursic, Leave about HBridge, Tell me about connections between 74HC595 and ULN2064B

Comment: I mean, How can i connect ULN2064 with 74HC595

Comment: (@MarkoBuršič: `130 dc size motor doesn't mean anything` That may be as it may be. Depending on context, *130 size DC motor* means a [Mabuchi "WX-130YZ-whatever" motor](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/search.html?method=4) (about 20 g, 1 W) or same size similar, WXYZwhatever telling about brushes, bearings, windings, the works.